# how to display pickerview when user enter first 4 digits values in textfield

Tags: ios, iphone, database, validation

I have one `UiTextField` Called MobileNumber. and two `pickerView` called Operator and circle. When I enter first 4 digits of my number in `textfield` it displays the Operator `pickerview`, 
how to call it when I enter first 4 digits value in `textfield` and display the `pickerview`

Comment: what did you tried yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` textField's `delegate` method for entering `numeric character`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        //This field accepts only numeric entries.
        return NO;
    }
    else //numeric value entered
    {
        NSString *strTxtField = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
        if(strTxtField.length == 4)
        {
            //show pickerview here
            //Set return NO if you don't want more character to be added to textfield
            //return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a notification that will be called on every single change in text field.

```
// Add a "textFieldDidChange" notification method to the text field control.
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Now here on this method textFieldDidChange: you can access your text field and check if user has entered 4 digits you can show the picker.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(newString.length == 4)
    {
        NSLog(@"show date picker");
       //Set return NO if you don't want more character to be added to textfield
        //return NO;
    }

    return newString.length <= 4;
}
```

make sure that your text field delegate set properly..